# Ouput the CSS Styles Rules in div (on Screen)

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say my task is to print out on the screen all the CSS rules with Javascript. I wrote the following code:

```
var outputDiv = document.createElement("div");
outputDiv.id = "output";
document.body.appendChild(outputDiv);

function cssOutput() {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;
    if (sheets.length > 0) {
        for (var i in sheets) {
            var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
            for (var j in rules) {
                var rule = rules[j].cssText;
                console.log(rule);
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = rule;
            }
        }
    }
}
//console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText);
cssOutput();
```

However, I got just "undefined" on the screen despite the fact that it is possible to log them.

Comment: Try adding it to your innerHTML instead of replacing it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are overwriting the output div with each iteration of your loop (so each rule overwrites the previous one).
Consider changing this line:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = rule;
```

to this line:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += rule; // Note "+=" not "="
```

such that each iteration will write the next rule.

Answer (score 2):

check the fiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/4cqcpngy/

```
var outputDiv = document.createElement("div");
outputDiv.id="output";
document.body.appendChild(outputDiv);

function cssOutput(){
     var sheets = document.styleSheets;
     if (sheets.length>0){
        for (var i in sheets){
             var rules = sheets[i].cssRules;
             for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++){
                 var rule = rules[j].cssText;
                 console.log(rule);
                 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += rule;
}}}}


cssOutput();
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited it with document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += rule; Now I will edit back to make your answer sense.

Comment: check the fiddle. it works. i added @dgavian answer to it.

Comment: thanks, it works! I made a very small mistake. Btw, "for (var j in rules){ }" line still can be left. That change is not necessary. The main point was "+=".

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
for (var j in rules){
```

you're using a for-in, which will iterate the properties on the rules object, which I don't think is what you want. You should change it to:

```
for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++)
```

Comment: That's fine but the console logs "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

Comment: I hadn't noticed this originally but it looks like you have the same issue with "for (var i in sheets){"